# How to fix 'strtok destroy original string' in c

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm writing a compiler for assembler, and I need to do parsing to the text I get from a file, without making any changes in the original String. The function I used to copy the String was `strcpy`to a buffer, and to cut the String was `strtok` to cut the buffer. 
Everything works perfect, but once I try to cut the original String after using the function `addressingConstantIndex` , I get `null`.

I tried to change the type of the buffer to a pointer of Character, it didn't really work. I guess the main problem it's in the way I copy the original String to the buffer.

```
int main(){
    char desti[MAXCHAR];
    char *temp;
    char *token;
    temp = "mov LIST[5] , r4";
    strcpy(desti,temp);
    printf("\ndest is : %s\n", desti);

    token = strtok(desti," ");

    printf("\nthe Token in Main is : %s \n", token);

    token = strtok(NULL, ",");

    printf("\nthe Token in Main is : %s\n", token);

    printf("\nThe value is %d \n ",addressingConstantIndex(token));

    token = strtok(NULL, " ,");

    printf("\nthe Token in Main is : %s\n", token);
    return 0;
}



int addressingConstantIndex(char * str) {
    char buf[43];
    char *token;
    int ans;
    strcpy(buf, str);
    token = strtok(buf, "[");
    printf("The string is %s\n",str);
    if (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("the token is %s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "]");
        printf("the token is %s\n", token);
        if(isOnlyNumber(token))
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            if (checkIfSpaces(token,0) == ERROR)
            {
                printf("ERROR: Extra characters after last bracket %s \n", str);
                ans = ERROR;
            } else
                ans = OK;
        } else {
            printf("ERROR: Unknown string - %s  - its not a macro & not a number.\n", token);
            ans = ERROR;
        }
    } else {
        printf("ERROR: %s , its not a LABEL", token);
        ans = ERROR;
    }
    return ans;
}


int isOnlyNumber(char *str) {
    int i, isNumber;
    i = 0;
    isNumber = 1;
    if (!isdigit(str[i]) && !(str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '+'))
    {
        isNumber = ERROR;
    }
    i++;
    while (i < strlen(str) && isNumber == 1)
    {
        if (!(isdigit(str[i]))) {
            if (isspace(str[i]))  
                isNumber = checkIfSpaces(str, i);
            else
                isNumber = ERROR;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return isNumber;
}


int checkIfSpaces(char *str, int index) {
    int i;
    if (str == NULL)
    {
        return OK;
    } else {
        for (i = index; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if (!isspace(str[i])) return ERROR;
        }
    }
    return OK;
}
```

The expecting result:

```
dest is : mov LIST[5] , r4

the Token in Main is : mov

the Token in Main is : LIST[5]
The string is LIST[5]
the token is LIST
the token is 5

The value is 1

the Token in Main is : r4
```

The real result:

```
dest is : mov LIST[5] , r4

the Token in Main is : mov

the Token in Main is : LIST[5]
The string is LIST[5]
the token is LIST
the token is 5

The value is 1

the Token in Main is : (null)
```

The difference It's in the last row of the result.

Comment: If you need to preserve the original string, either make a copy of the string and use `strtok()` on the copy, or don't use `strtok()`.

Comment: Also note that you can't use `strtok()` to analyze two different strings concurrently.  Basically, `strtok()` is often the wrong function to use; this is one of the many times when it is the wrong function.  Try `strspn()` and `strcspn()` instead.

Comment: I need to do some validation to each part of the String i get.

Comment: Does your platform have `strtok_r`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `strtok()` maintains a single static pointer to the current string location.  So in `addressingConstantIndex()`, you start processing the local `buf`, so that when you return to `main()` it is no longer parsing `desti` but the now out of scope `buf` from `addressingConstantIndex()`.

The simplest change to your existing code would be to use `strtok_r()` (or `strtok_s()` on Windows):

```
char* context = 0 ;
token = strtok_r( desti, " ", &context ) ;
printf("\nthe Token in Main is : %s \n", token);
token = strtok_r( NULL, ",", &context ) ;
...
```

Then similarly in `addressingConstantIndex()`:

```
char* context = 0 ;
token = strtok_r(buf, "[", &context);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` replaces the separator in the string with a NULL on each call. Your code is finding the  'LIST[5]' token at the main level, at which point it has replaced the ',' with a NULL.

In `addressingConstantIndex`, `strtok` is reset with a new string and parses correctly (though your function is typed void instead of int).

At at the main level again, `strtok` is not being reset, so it is continuing to parse the string used in `addressingConstantIndex`.

To fix this you need to reset `strtok` again to continue. However you can't just call it with `strtok(desti,",")` as the `desti` has all the separators set to NULL from previous calls.

A quick solution is to copy the token to feed into `addressingConstantIndex` at the main level, and complete the main level before parsing at the next level.

```
int main(){
    char desti[MAXCHAR];
    char *temp;
    char *token;
    temp = "mov LIST[5] , r4";
    strcpy(desti,temp);
    printf("\ndest is : %s\n", desti);

    token = strtok(desti," ");
    printf("\nMnemonic : %s \n", token);

    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    printf("\nLIst bit: %s\n", token);

    char buf[80];       //Save the token 
    strcpy(buf, token);

    token = strtok(NULL, " ,"); //Finish this level of processing
    printf("\nRegister: %s\n", token);

    //Continue at the next level with copy
    printf("\nThe value is %d \n ",addressingConstantIndex(buf)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Though a `strtok_r` solution might suit your needs better going forward